# Managing SQLite Connections in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, architecture

I have a (hopefully) quick question regarding handling SQLite database connections in Android. I have an app that is composed, naturally, of several activities. I have no trouble creating/updating/querying the database, as I've created a single, dedicated class to handle that work via SQLiteOpenHelper, etc.

My question is this: since these activities all share this same database, is this usually implemented as a single, static member, or should each activity own its own connection? My concern of course is the cost of re-connecting to the database in each activity.

Or, put another way, is there any reason not to just store a singleton instance?

I'm also wondering if there's something going on behind the scenes similar to .NET's connection pooling to reduce the cost of opening connections.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Connection opening in SQLite is about 0.2ms.

The best practice tells us to open and close the connection each time we need one.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes finding an "official" best practice is a challenge.

Answer (score 9):

Just use [SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()) and [SQLiteOpenHelper.getWriteableDatabase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()) - Android will manage and cache the connection so you don't need to.

In fact, refer to the official Google [Using Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) documentation:

> To write to and read from the
>   database, call getWritableDatabase()
>   and getReadableDatabase(),
>   respectively. These both return a
>   SQLiteDatabase

Comment: Thanks for the response @RivieraKid. The official documents didn't go into a lot of detail as to the expense of opening the connections, which is where I was going with the question. Knowing that there are measures behind the scenes to manage/reuse the connections, and that there is an acceptable cost of calling those methods as I need them (rather than holding onto the database object returned) helps tremendously.

Comment: But should I close the returning SQLiteDatabase each time I call those functions?
I have a SQLiteDatabase with a lot of small functions, each one of them calls one of the "getXXXDatabase". Should I close the database at the end of every method? Won't I lose the cache advantages? Or does Android keep it anyway?