# Do I need call close() when I use getWritableDatabase()?

Tags: java, android, sqliteopenhelper

If I have code like this

```
private final SQLiteDatabase database;
private final SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
// ...
this.database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
// ...
```

Do I need to call close() explicitly?

I am confused by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18595604/4932519

Take a look to doc for getWritableDatabase():

> Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this
>   method every time you need to write to the database. (**Make sure to
>   call close() when you no longer need the database.**)

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One call to `close()` should always be paired with every call to `getWritableDatabase()`.

When you're calling `getWritableDatabase()` once for every query, you should also call `close()` when you've finished with the query.

When you're calling `getWritableDatabase()` when the activity starts up, and save the reference, you should call `close()` when the activity shuts down.

Comment: My answer and that answer do not contradict each other.

Comment: How about "and never explicitly close that instance"?

Comment: It will be implicitly closed eventually. Explicitly calling `close()` is more important when you're calling `getWritableDatabase()` repeatedly, because all those objects might pile up before the next garbage collection, and eat up all available file handles.

Comment: "closed eventually" using finalize method?

Comment: Yes, at the next garbage collection.

Comment: But finalize() not always called. Is not bad practice?

Comment: Yes, it's bad practice. But a single not-yet-closed database object does not matter, and the activity will be shut down only when memory is tight, so there is likely to be a garbage collection.

Comment: I've understood. Thank you again.